# EAR file name from Weblogic REST interface

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

Is it possible to query (from the Weblogic Server REST inteterface) the name of the .ear files of the applications that have been deployed on the Server ? How?

Comment: what do you want and why do you want ?

Comment: In our Organization EAR files are built using a name convention that include the verion of the module (e.g. Module_A_ver_1_1 ).
I need to make a dashboard that show the deployed version of all the modules on each server.

Comment: so, you need list of all deployed application on weblogic. Is it ?

Comment: yes. that is what I am trying to achieve. Any idea? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WLST scipt, which give you the list of application deployed in specific domain.

Here is sample code :

```
connect('weblogic','weblogic','t3://localhost:7001')
cd ('AppDeployments')
myapps=cmo.getAppDeployments()

for appName in myapps:
       domainConfig()
       cd ('/AppDeployments/'+appName.getName()+'/Targets')
       mytargets = ls(returnMap='true')
       domainRuntime()
       cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
       cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
       for targetinst in mytargets:
             curstate4=cmo.getCurrentState(appName.getName(),targetinst)
             print '-----------', curstate4, '-----------', appName.getName()
```

So, everything in WLST scripting start from connecting to weblogic admin. And, then perform your task.